# json.load() function give strange 'UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode' error

Tags: python, json, file, parsing

I'm trying to read a JSON file I have saved in a text file using the python `.loads()` function. I will later parse the JSON to obtain a specific value.

I keep getting this error message. When I google it, there are no results.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position > 85298: ordinal not in range(128)

Here is the full error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File ".../FirstDegreeKanyeScript.py", >line 10, in      data=json.load(data_file)   File >"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/**in>it**.py", line 265, in load     return loads(fp.read(),   File >"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/encodings>/ascii.py", line 26, in decode     return codecs.ascii_decode(input, >self.errors)[0] UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 >in position 85298: ordinal not in range(128)

Here is my code:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with
open("/Users/.../KanyeAllSongs.txt") as data_file:
    data=json.load(data_file)

pprint(data)
```

I've tried adding `data.decode('utf-8')` under the `json.load`, but I still get the same error.

Any ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: Which version of python are you using? And which encoding is the file in?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Specify the encoding in the `open` call.

```
# encoding is a keyword argument
open("/Users/.../KanyeAllSongs.txt", encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    data=json.load(data_file)
```

Comment: @Alik  i get 

    open('filename.js', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
                                          ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @FightFireWithFire - Should be updated shortly (waiting for peer review: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16132026)

Comment: There should be probably `with open(...) as ...`.

Answer (score 0):

found it on Google. In my case, all ended up with:

```py
open("/Users/.../KanyeAllSongs.txt", "rb") as data_file:
   data=json.load(data_file)
```

I added `rb` to open the file in binary mode.