# How to fix UnicodeDecodeError while reading JSON file in python

Tags: python, json

I'm reading a json file in python which has huge amount of imported goods data with their names and taxes. I want to input an item name and search through that file to get tax of that item.

```
import json

with open("./Files/CD_Data.json") as file:
    #item = input("Enter item name: ")
    reader = json.load(file)
    print(reader)
```

But when display all data then this error comes up.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1626249: `character maps to <undefined>`
```

Comment: Maybe `json.load(file.read())` or `json.loads(file)`? check the difference between `.load()` and `.loads()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json.load() function give strange 'UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35051867/json-load-function-give-strange-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decod)

Comment: Or maybe it does not knew how to interpret some character. try to set `encoding="utf8"`

Answer (score 15):

It is reasonable to give encoding parameter every time you open a file. Use this:

```
import json

with open("./Files/CD_Data.json", encoding="utf8") as file:
    #item = input("Enter item name: ")
    reader = json.load(file)
    print(reader)
```

Comment: Getting ```JSONDecodeError: Extra data``` using this exact method. File loading in as ```TextIOWrapper```