# Python - Remove elevents from JSON containing a certain value

Tags: python, arrays, json, spotify

I'm trying to mass-delete a bunch of items from my spotify streaming data by specific artists (mostly just trying to remove a bunch of audiobooks). The data is in the form of a bunch of JSONs formatted like this:

```
  {
    "ts": "2017-05-04T13:26:03Z",
    "username": [redacted],
    "platform": "Android OS 5.1.1 API 22 (samsung, SM-J500H)",
    "ms_played": 11887,
    "conn_country": "GB",
    "ip_addr_decrypted": null,
    "user_agent_decrypted": null,
    "master_metadata_track_name": "Just Breathe",
    "master_metadata_album_artist_name": "Pearl Jam",
    "master_metadata_album_album_name": "Backspacer",
    "spotify_track_uri": "spotify:track:2m2dgHoAEZUkmxamsOwyQg",
    "episode_name": null,
    "episode_show_name": null,
    "spotify_episode_uri": null,
    "reason_start": "clickrow",
    "reason_end": null,
    "shuffle": "FALSE",
    "skipped": null,
    "offline": "FALSE",
    "offline_timestamp": 1.49385E+12,
    "incognito_mode": "FALSE"
  },
  {
    "ts": "2017-05-04T13:26:32Z",
    "username": [redacted],
    "platform": "Android OS 5.1.1 API 22 (samsung, SM-J500H)",
    "ms_played": 11887,
    "conn_country": "GB",
    "ip_addr_decrypted": null,
    "user_agent_decrypted": null,
    "master_metadata_track_name": "Just Breathe",
    "master_metadata_album_artist_name": "Pearl Jam",
    "master_metadata_album_album_name": "Backspacer",
    "spotify_track_uri": "spotify:track:2m2dgHoAEZUkmxamsOwyQg",
    "episode_name": null,
    "episode_show_name": null,
    "spotify_episode_uri": null,
    "reason_start": "clickrow",
    "reason_end": null,
    "shuffle": "FALSE",
    "skipped": null,
    "offline": "FALSE",
    "offline_timestamp": 1.49385E+12,
    "incognito_mode": "FALSE"
  },
  {
    "ts": "2017-05-04T13:30:17Z",
    "username": [redacted],
    "platform": "Android OS 5.1.1 API 22 (samsung, SM-J500H)",
    "ms_played": 0,
    "conn_country": "GB",
    "ip_addr_decrypted": null,
    "user_agent_decrypted": null,
    "master_metadata_track_name": "The Sirens of Time Part 1, Track 1",
    "master_metadata_album_artist_name": "Doctor Who",
    "master_metadata_album_album_name": "Main Range 1: The Sirens of Time",
    "spotify_track_uri": "spotify:track:64vQITW6SxB2fgxulsZ5Ix",
    "episode_name": null,
    "episode_show_name": null,
    "spotify_episode_uri": null,
    "reason_start": "clickrow",
    "reason_end": null,
    "shuffle": "FALSE",
    "skipped": null,
    "offline": "FALSE",
    "offline_timestamp": 1.4939E+12,
    "incognito_mode": "FALSE"
  },
```

How, for example, would I go about removing all elements where "master_metadata_album_artist_name" is equal to "Doctor Who"? And is there a way to do this for multiple JSON files at once?

Tried:

```
import json
obj  = json.load(open("Streaming_History_Audio_2016-2018_1.json"))
                                                      
for i in xrange(len(obj)):
    if obj[i]["master_metadata_album_artist_name"] == "Doctor Who":
        obj.pop(i)
        break
                                     
open("updated-file.json", "w").write(
    json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
)
```

Result:

```
C:\Users\tim_f\Downloads\my_spotify_data(2)\Spotify Extended Streaming History 2023 - Copy>py del.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tim_f\Downloads\my_spotify_data(2)\Spotify Extended Streaming History 2023 - Copy\del.py", line 2, in <module>
    obj  = json.load(open("Streaming_History_Audio_2016-2018_1.json"))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\tim_f\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
                 ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\tim_f\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 181341: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: The error is likely due to an encoding issue,  it is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52609521/1152381), You have to iterate over the directory if there are multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

You are encountering an error while opening the file. This is most likely due to an encoding issue.
Try this:

```
obj = json.load(open("Streaming_History_Audio_2016-2018_1.json", encoding="utf8"))
```

Comment: Hi
The code is now this:

import json
obj = json.load(open("Streaming_History_Audio_2016-2018_1.json", encoding="utf8"))
                                                      
for i in range(len(obj)):
    if obj[i]["master_metadata_album_artist_name"] == "Doctor Who":
        obj.pop(i)
        break
                                     
open("updated-file.json", "w").write(
    json.dumps(obj)
)

The code runs, but it only seems to duplicate the file without deleting anything.

Comment: First of all I would suggest to store the data in the json file with the correct format. Eg. [     {"artist1" : "xyz",      "album1": "abc"     },     {"artist2" : "xyz",      "album2": "abc"     } ]
The code will now process each element  as a dictionary in the list. When you have to remove a specific element, it is similar to removing an item from the list.

Answer (score 0):

update: Think I figured it out

```
import json

# Open the JSON file for reading
with open('Streaming_History_Audio_2018_2.json', 'r', encoding="utf8") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

# Filter out elements with "master_metadata_album_artist_name" as "Doctor Who"
filtered_data = [item for item in data if item.get('master_metadata_album_artist_name') != "Doctor Who"]

# Open the JSON file for writing
with open('Streaming_History_Audio_2018_2_filtered.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(filtered_data, json_file, indent=2)

print("Filtered data has been written to Streaming_History_Audio_2018_2_filtered.json")
```